# Update multiple columns in Oracle using PlaceHolders

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to use Update query in C# to update multiple columns into Oracle database, but I am facing multiple errors. Can you please help me in simplifying the query?

One of the Error is 
`ERROR [NA000] [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-00927: missing equal sign`

```
string OCommand = "UPDATE " + tableName + "  SET (" + columns + ") = " + values + " WHERE CUSTOMERID = " + COLUMNS_CUSTOMERID + "";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(OCommand);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = connection;
connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Please show the resulting SQL statement. We have no way to tell what syntax errors hide in `values` or `columns`.  And do you really need to build the SQL completely on-the-fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set each columns values independently. eg:

```
UPDATE myTable SET column1 = <value1>, column2 = <value2>, ... WHERE ...
```

Comment: Actually, i am going to take input for Column and values from Text fields, which is why I am  using placeholders "+columns+" for column name and "+values+" for column values, Is it a way I can shorten the query to be used in C# code

Comment: @samarkhatri Yes i saw what you wanted to do but you can't write the query like that. Oracle is very strict. And by the way you should use parameters instead to prevent SQL Injections